# How can I set a command to run in an interval in Java?

Tags: java, timer

This is a simple game:
- Bee gets some honey from the flower's nectar.
- The nectar gets empty but needs to automatically refill honey.
- There are 5 stages of the honey refill [smallest drop of honey-biggest]

Question: How can I set a command to automatically refill honey on the nectar? With a 5 second interval on each honey refill stage?

So far, I have this code, but it is stuck with the first stage of honey refill. I need the drops of honey to grow.

Thanks in advance!

```
    public void update() {
      timer++;

        if (isEmpty) {
            if (timer >= 300 /* 60*5초 */) {
                sx = 0;
                sx += w; 
                timer = 0;
                System.out.println("꿀참");
            }
        }
        isEmpty = false;
    }
```

Comment: Is this question still active? Consider marking any answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call update, you are resetting *isEmpty* to false, before you can refill the honey. Make an if statement that only resets *isEmpty* if the nectar is filled.